# How to solve compilation error on inclusion of GWT Material Design

Tags: gwt, material-design, carousel

I want to use MaterialCarousel on my project and hence I think I set up my project accordingly. Here is what I am getting while I tried to compile.

```
Compiling module org.vadiraj.curiosity.GWTCuriosity
   Ignored 240 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'gwt.material.design.addins.client.carousel.MaterialCarousel'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'gwt/material/design/addins/client/carousel/MaterialCarousel.java'
         [ERROR] Line 135: Lambda expressions are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
   [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

Comment: I am using JRE System Library 1.8.0_181

Comment: Can you confirm which version of GWT (and GMD) you are using? If you are using an old enough version, Java 1.8 might not be supported. Also, how are you running the GWT compiler (and can you add your ant/mvn/gradle config or the command line args you are passing in)?

Comment: GWT Version - 2.7.0

I am right clicking on the eclipse project and navigating to 'GWT' and then clicking on 'Compile' option.

This is my 'Program Arguments' --> `-nosuperDevMode -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl GWTCuriosity.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort auto -port auto -war C:\gitrepos\eclipse-workplace\GWTCuriosity\war org.vadiraj.curiosity.GWTCuriosity `

This is my VM Arguments --> -Xmx512g

By the way, what is GMD?

Answer (score 2):

GWT 2.7 does not support Java 8, and so does not support any recent build of GWT Material Design. GWT 2.8.0 was released in 2016, and the latest version as of this answer is 2.8.2, and generally should be used instead of an earlier 2.8 build.

Comment: Tell me Colin, How comfortable are you (Or the people working with the new GWT) with SuperDev mode? It is hard for me to use SuperDev mode where there is no Java debugging. 

We would like to debug Java code line by line using Eclipse IDE. We were so comfortable for many years with Classic Dev mode. Now with the recent push towards SuperDev mode, none of our team members are liking it. 

Are we missing something? This is the only reason why we stick to GWT 2.7 where we can still use Classic Dev Mode with 'nosuperDevMode' set.

Comment: I like SuperDevMode a lot more than DevMode. It is much faster, and you can step using Eclipse or IntelliJ no problem. For eclipse use the plugin by Branflake https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin ; check out his videos on how to set it up https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU7ZQVLR5Zo&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT

Comment: Two questions:


1. How is it helpful when you cannot use the 'Inspect variable' feature in case of SuperDev mode? I want to see the values which the local variables hold. Is this possible?


2. In the classic dev mode, I can perform an instant edit of java code while debugging and I could see it being reflected on the UI. How can I achieve this in the Super Dev mode?

Comment: Legacy Dev Mode still works in GWT 2.8 (and will work in all future 2.x versions, but nothing past that) - the limiting factor is only that you must have an ancient browser installed. For eclipse debugging of SDM, consider the SDBG plugin, which lets eclipse debug source maps - you see your java line by line, but variables are still a bit hard to observe.

Comment: Sorry, we replied at the same time - "inspect variable" indeed does not work by itself, instead you just look for the variable in the list - and editing code and having it refresh instantly is hit-or-miss even in legacy dev mode in my experience, so I never was able to count on it, but always refreshed between changes anyway.

Comment: You said 'Legacy Dev Mode still works in GWT 2.8'. This is not true. Please check this out. **Release Notes for 2.8.0 (RC1)** [link](http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html)                     `Classic dev mode deprecated.You can switch back to dev mode for your test cases temporarily by passing gwt.args=‘-devMode’.`

Comment: "Deprecated" means "Discouraged" and "Should be avoided", not "Removed" - I can promise you that as a member of the GWT Steering committee we have no intentions of removing or disabling Legacy Dev Mode in the 2.x series, though it certainly is not getting any new features. It doesn't work in modern browsers, it requires a lot of work to maintain, but for the old code that was written to work with it, it will keep working. This may or may not include GMD.